# read value from another table based on ID and insert value into log table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

The following trigger is used to log data from `TBL_ADM_USER` table into `TBL_LogTable` table

trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[User_Insert]
ON [dbo].[TBL_ADM_USER]

AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO TBL_LogTable
SELECT CONCAT('User "' ,i.fullname,'" has been added into ', i.group_id), 
'USER', 'Add', SYSDATETIME(), i.creator_user_id
FROM inserted i;

END
```

the `group_id`is foreign key in user table and primary key in `group table`. My problem is instead of log `i.group_id` into log table, I want to log `group_name` where `id = i.group_id`. How can I do that using  current trigger ?

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  INSERT INTO TBL_LogTable
    SELECT CONCAT('User "' ,i.fullname,'" has been added into ', (select group_name from group_table where id=i.group_id)), 
    'USER', 'Add', SYSDATETIME(), i.creator_user_id
    FROM inserted i;
```

try this query.